# Looking for text in a list of UILabel in subviews

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilabel, subviews

I try to access to the text of my UILabels in subviews

```
for (UIView *myView in recognizer.view.subviews) {
     ...
            }
```

How can I check the text of my UILabels found in this research?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for (UIView *myView in recognizer.view.subviews) {
    if([myView isKindOfClass: [UILabel class]]){
        //check ur Label text here
        UILabel * myLabel = (UILabel *) myView;
        if ([myLabel.text isEqualToString: @"Your String"])
        {
            //GO For Ur Logic Here
        }
    } 
}
```

Hope it helps you.. happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, just after adding "]" at the end of if…statement
if([maVue isKindOfClass: [UILabel class]] == YES)